# Почему не правильно позиционируется Popup?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, wpf-шаблоны

Переопределил стандартный шаблон `MenuItem`. Дочерний элемент `MenuItem`'a "О программе "Угадай себя" позиционируется так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы левая граница `popup` была выровнена по левой границе родительского элемента. Этого получается добиться только установив `Placement="Relative"` и при помощи `VerticalOffset`, `HorizontalOffset` установить нужные позиции, но ведь, если этот стиль подключить к другим `MenuItem`'ам, то позиционирование "поедет". Что сделано не так из-за чего не выравнивается позиционирование?

`XAML`:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" 
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                            Margin="3" 
                            Visibility="Collapsed" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                                        Grid.Column="0" 
                                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" 
                                        ContentSource="Header" 
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
                            AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" 
                            IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            HorizontalOffset=""
                            VerticalOffset="">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" 
                                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <!--<Canvas x:Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect"
                                                    Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"
                                                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"
                                                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>-->
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--<Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>-->
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Люди, хелп, плс!)

Comment: А чем обычное `Menu` не угодило?

Comment: Заказчик потребовал )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проще, без наворотов с переопределением шаблонов. Вместо этого просто использовать как базовый стиль - стиль пункта главного меню. Отступы можно подстроить под свои нужды. Чтобы избавиться от верктикальной палки, которая отделяет иконки, я просто переопределил шаблон айтем-панели и покрасил его в стандартный цвет фона меню.

```xml
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="Help" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
        <MenuItem Header="Me"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Please"/>
        <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Static SystemColors.MenuBrushKey}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще у вас похоже на то что менюшки выпадают с позиционированием по правому краю от пункта основного меню, а не по левому. Здесь я помочь не могу, проверяйте настройки операционной системы.

Comment: Действительно так проще!) Спасибо!) Но вложенный `MenuItem` все равно не выравнивается по-левому краю ((((